# android studio aapt build timeout when dealing with big raw files

Tags: android

I try to include a file with size 1.6G in the raw folder using android studio 4.2.1. The aapt will timeout in 10 minutes. Of course we can put the file on the cloud or server, and then download it  when user use the app first time. Apple Xcode could easily do it without any problem. This is how android studio will never be a top tier IDE: you can't just put a bunch of open source tools together and hope that they will work together with a miracle. You need someone to take care of  the overall performance like Xcode. Gradle needs a 5G memory (org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5000m) and still failed to comprehend a 1.6G file.  It keeps on phasing out good stuff like gcc, ndk-build, roll out useless features, gui with different syntax..., inventing useless new languages. llvm really give them that silly choice.

AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0 Failed to shutdown within timeout
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Failed to shut down within 30 seconds. Forcing shutdown
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.stopProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:253)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.shutDown(Aapt2Daemon.kt:171)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError(Aapt2Daemon.kt:206)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError$default(Aapt2Daemon.kt:191)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.kt:129)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:176)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$leasingAapt2Daemon$1.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:199)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.services.PartialInProcessResourceProcessor.link(PartialInProcessResourceProcessor.kt:47)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnableKt.processResources(Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnable.kt:73)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$Companion.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:874)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$Companion.access$invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:726)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction.run(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:371)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:67)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:60)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:200)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.1-7147631-windows Daemon #0: Link timed out, attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 1):

Don't include a 1.6 GB file as a raw file.  First off, your app probably won't work if you do, as resources are loaded into memory at boot and you'd be over the RAM limit for a single app.  Secondly, that's an incredibly long download for your APK.  If you absolutely must have a 1.6 GB file as part of your app, it should be an expansion file or a download, not part of the app itself.

If you absolutely must put it as part of the apk itself-  it can't be a raw file. It needs to be an asset.

And really, if you don't understand why a giant RAW file is a bad idea, you shouldn't be ranting about XCode (quite possibly the worst IDE I've used since the DOS age) vs Android Studio.  You obviously don't understand the platform and are abusing it.  Your app would have used gigabytes more memory than it should have.

Answer (score 0):

For production, download is definitely be an option. I am just testing the application at the beginning stage of the app life cycle. Xcode and Vstudio c++ is definitely a piece of art. IntelliJ IDEA maybe a better choice over android studio. Obliviously, cutting files into small files and assemble them back at runtime could avoid the problem. Game development usually do it in old days . Ironically, Iphone tend to have less RAM while android Phone has more RAM,  but IOS do a better job of make use of them... Trying to make full use of resources is definitely not abusing it... IOS run same c++ code smoothly.  Android with 6G should be able to run it.  My previous successful experience  with android is loading up 1G file with 3-4 RAM phone.  latest android tends to have 8G RAM. Bottleneck is on android studio. It is a real problem.  A chain is only as strong as its weakest link.